# What does saying "without the service" mean when paying the bill at a restaurant?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I just heard an actor in a movie say "without the service" when paying the bill at a restaurant. (The movie was [*The Strays*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strays_(film)), from 2023 - navigate to ***08:19 mins*** from start).

I assume it's British English, but still, this seems to be rare, because I've never before heard anyone saying "without the service" when paying food bill(s) at any eatery or restaurant. When the actor said "without the service" the waiter replied with "Thank you."

Does this just mean "Keep the change"? If so, then why does it mean that?

Also, what's the origin of this phrase?

Comment: What was the full context?

Comment: We can only guess. Maybe he was querying the bill, or asking for the bill without the service charge? Maybe he was talking about something else entirely.

Comment: Edited the question to attempt clarify the context, that's all there is to the conversation

Comment: It isn't a "phrase". It is probably a question: Is this bill without the service? service is the charge for being served in a restaurant.

Comment: @VickyDev Please be as specific as possible. (Which movie? At what point in the movie?) It's possible that someone who can recall that scene or decides to look it up will be able to get a better idea and answer your question. Knowing whether the scriptwriters were British, American, etc. may also provide a hint. The time-period of the movie could also help. And so on.

Comment: Without seeing the movie, it is hard to tell. I had a waiting job when on college vacation; one customer had a bill of £17 and said "Take £20" and I replied "thank you very much." But he did not leave, and asked where his change is. In this case, the customer might mean "I am not paying the service charge."

Comment: Thanks for the edit: only reviews and the trailer are available on YouTube.

Comment: The film is a Hollywood comedy. In the US, restaurant *service* is the tip. *Without* would mean I'm tipping you separately. Could be good news.

Comment: @Lambie It's definitely a statement, not a question. She says it as she gives the payment to the waitress.

Comment: To all the guys here and also to the one who initially downvoted this question which I guess may have been appropriate at that time, but I think now if this question has created such a stir and interest in people, then I genuinely think, this now deserves some upvotes, doesn't it ? So urging you guys to put some upvotes, so this question gains more attention which will ultimately be helpful to us in getting more correct and apt answers(from different opinions & perspectives) once the context becomes accurately clear..

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is definitely a service, in England or Britain. That said it doesn’t necessarily mean she’s stuffing the waitress, although in the show you’re referring to, one gets the impression that is her intent. However, it could be that she wants to leave her own, larger tip in hand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

I just watched this section on Netflix. For reference, the main character says, "Without the service. Thank you." to the waiter, confirmed by the closed captions.

Based on [this article](https://www.ft.com/content/3eee193e-dc0b-11e7-9504-59efdb70e12f), I think "service" refers to the VAT tax. The character essentially says, "Here is the money for the meal, minus the voluntary VAT you applied.". I don't pay VAT myself, but that seems to make sense, given the context in the movie and the article.

Comment: VAT isn't optional in the UK, it's automatically included in the bill. Many restaurants do apply a service charge, which is optional, to the bill (typically 10-15%) that is used to supplement the server's wages (effectively replacing a tip). So someone who says "Without the service. Thank you." is short-changing the serving staff.

Comment: Not only is VAT not an optional charge, as @KillingTime has pointed out, but retail establishments are required to quote prices inclusive of VAT, so a restaurant's tariff is inclusive of the tax.

Comment: @KillingTime - The article I noted is called "Why I hate voluntary service charges in restaurants, It is a double VAT whammy at the expense of diners and taxpayers" and he gives the example of a London. So there seems to be merit to what I was saying. Maybe the character is not the kind who thinks she should pay the service charge.

Comment: You should read the article more closely. It is objecting to people paying service charges based on the price inclusive of VAT rather than the price exclusive of VAT, because the former is larger. Hence people are paying (in the author's opinion) the (net) price of the meal + VAT + service charge on the net price of the meal + service charge on the VAT. The last 2 are optional; the net price and VAT are not.